# Why doesn't my route codeigniter go to correct action controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here my route

```
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/get_show/$1';
$route['posts/(:any)/dosomething'] ='posts/get_dosomething/$1';
```

Controller

```
public function get_show($id)
public function get_dosomething($id)
```

With the link `posts/1/dosomething`, route always points to the action `get_show`, it never goes to `get_dosomething`

Any idea how to fix it ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must first route like this

```
$route['posts/(:any)/dosomething'] ='posts/get_dosomething/$1';
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/get_show/$1';
```

Comment: Oh dear, that seems silly. Could you explain why it works that way ?

Comment: Becaue this `any` is greedy. Unlike other frameworks, CI treats it as optional for any number of parameter.

Comment: it's like a book .. also don't jump to the end.. you said in your routes, that posts/(:any) is calling get_show()... and now you calling posts/(:any)/something... therefore it must be in this order

Comment: That's a bit wrong approach from CI. :any is one segment. If i say `post/foo` then it is ok. But if it is `post/foo/bar` then it shouldn't pass through that filter because there is an extra segment.

Comment: To explain why it works CI routes by the first rule that matches (and it isn't just CI that does this a lot of systems do). So since (:any) is a wildcard it will match anything in the first segment after posts and stops. You have to go from the most specific to the widest range when routing, keep that rule in mind and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

because `posts/1/dosomething` is always fallen under $route['posts/(:any)'] . change one of your routes condition