# Codeigniter PHP Missing Argument 2 Error?

Tags: codeigniter, uri, segments

I'm having an issue with my correctly displaying my URLs for my website. I'm using the latest version of Codeigniter.

I'm getting the below error message. I was doing some research and I think my issue is URI segments but I'm perplexed as to how to fix the problem.

My goal is to get the URL to look nice this
(_states is a sub directory folder on my localhost)
    mydomain.com/_states/dealers/Florida (This URL actually works)
    mydomain.com/_states/dealers/Florida/Miami (not working)
    mydomain.com/_states/dealers/Florida/Miami/8 (not working)

I've also provided the syntax for my routes.php and model_data.php. How would you guys going about fixing this problem? Thanks everyone in advance.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 2 for Site::getDealersCity()

Filename: controllers/site.php

Line Number: 43

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: city

Filename: controllers/site.php

Line Number: 47
```

Site Controller

```
   public function getDealersCity($state, $city){
     //$city = $this->uri->segment(3);
     //echo "$city";
     if(is_null($state)) return false;
     if(is_null($city)) return false;
     $this->load->model('model_data');
     $data['statecity'] = $this->model_data->get_database_by_cities($state,$city);
     $this->load->view('statecity',$data);
   }
```

Model_data.php function

```
function get_database_by_cities($state, $city){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('states',
    array('state' => $state,
    'city' => $city)
    );
    if($query->num_rows()) return $query->result();
    return null;
}
```

Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['dealers/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/getUniqueDealerInfo/$3";
$route['dealers/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/getDealersCity/$2";
$route['dealers/(:any)'] = "site/getCities/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$route['dealers/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/getUniqueDealerInfo/$3";
$route['dealers/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/getDealersCity/$2";
```

The routes are conflicting in nature, one route overrides other.

Try using

```
$route['dealers/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/getDealersCity/$1/$2";
```

And there is no function for

> getUniqueDealerInfo

Have a look at the answers here [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14660267/1112120)